# COUNT from single column and seperate it into 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table "rating" in my database.

```
attraction      customer      rate
------------------------------------
attrac1         cust1         like
attrac2         cust1         dislike 
attrac1         cust2         like
```

What SQL should i write to make the output become like this

```
attraction      like       dislike
----------------------------------
attrac1           2           0
attrac2           0           1
```

I tried this

```
SELECT a_id,
(SELECT COUNT(rate) FROM rating WHERE rate = 'like') as 'Like',
(SELECT COUNT(rate) FROM rating WHERE rate = 'dislike') as 'Dislike'
FROM rating
```

But I cant get the result that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach:

```
SELECT a_id,
    SUM(Case when rate='like' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Like',
    SUM(Case when rate='dislike' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Dislike'
FROM rating
Group BY A_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I never know there can be a if else statement inside SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  Attraction,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Rate = 'Like' THEN Customer END) [Like],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Rate = 'DisLike' THEN Customer END) [DisLike]
FROM    Rating
GROUP BY Attraction
```